# How to commit an uncommitted mysql query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, isolation-level, mysql-connector-python

I am using MySQL DB, and use python's MySQL-connector to connect with it. I try to insert a record to MySQL using

```
def insert_users(first_name, last_name, country):
  conn, cursor=connection()
    cursor.execute(
      """
      INSERT INTO users (first_name, last_name, country_code) 
      SELECT %s,%s, code 
      FROM countries 
      WHERE countries.name=%s
      """, (first_name, last_name, country)
    )
```

but I forget to commit after execute, and then I use the same function to insert the same data with a commit but when I check the table, I find the primary_key starts from 2 instead of 1, which means the data is somehow existing (but uncommitted?) but what should I do to make it recover to a normal state, i.e commit the data I want to insert?
my isolation level is repeatable-read.
and i try to kill the connection through process id but i got the error "Query execution was interrupted", this is the result of show processlist

```
| Id | User | Host            | db    | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
 82 | root | localhost       | test2 | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist |
```

what should i do, i want to either commit the query or get rid of it. anyone can help? thanks in advance, Emergent...

Comment: don't depend on an auto_increment primary key to be anything other than a unique value. A transaction that starts will consume one value, but upon its abort the ID is lost. It no longer exists and neither does the inserts that occurred within the transaction.

Comment: it doesn't exist? but it still uses an auto_increment id? how do i fill the second row with other recordt then? since in other table i need to reference to the id as foreign key

Comment: ignore the fact there is a missing number. You should be using last_insert_id (however its accessed in python) to determine the value that got given to your insert, and use this as the FK when you insert into the other table.